# How to mirror a shape (DFF) in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I Found an example drawing a network of DFFs [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/d-flip-flops-and-shift-register/). The DFFs are chained to each other from left to right.

How can I draw the same circuit, whereas the chaining direction is reverse?

Comment: Try to give `[xscale=-1]` to nodes. But honestly this is fragile; better `\pgfdeclareshape{mirror dff}`.

Comment: Thank @Symbol1, declare another shape is better solution before the [xscale=-1] will make the text mirrored too.